# Please help me with apex script to assign a permission set to a permission set group in apex

Tags: apex, script

```
String permissionSetName = 'DE_Access_Application_Team_Assignment';
String permissionSetGroupName = 'Digital_Experience_LenderAI_PS_Group';

PermissionSet myPermissionSet = [SELECT Id FROM PermissionSet WHERE Name = :permissionSetName LIMIT 1];
PermissionSetGroup myPermissionSetGroup = [SELECT Id FROM PermissionSetGroup WHERE DeveloperName = :permissionSetGroupName LIMIT 1];

if (myPermissionSet != null && myPermissionSetGroup != null) {
    // Check if the assignment already exists
    List<PermissionSetAssignment> existingAssignments = [SELECT Id FROM PermissionSetAssignment WHERE AssigneeId = :myPermissionSetGroup.Id AND PermissionSetId = :myPermissionSet.Id LIMIT 1];

    if (existingAssignments.isEmpty()) {
        // Create a new PermissionSetAssignment
        PermissionSetAssignment myPermissionSetAssignment = new PermissionSetAssignment(
            AssigneeId = myPermissionSetGroup.Id,
            PermissionSetId = myPermissionSet.Id
        );

        insert myPermissionSetAssignment;

        System.debug('Permission Set ' + permissionSetName + ' assigned to Permission Set Group ' + permissionSetGroupName);
    } else {
        System.debug('Permission Set ' + permissionSetName + ' is already assigned to Permission Set Group ' + permissionSetGroupName);
    }
} else {
    System.debug('Permission Set or Permission Set Group not found.');
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Right now, you have a statement and a code dump, but you haven't told us what the issue is. Please [edit] your question to include that information. The more details you can give, the better.

Answer (score 2):

When using the query form of:

```
sObject varName = [select ... from ...];
```

If no rows are returned, an exception is thrown.

Further, `PermissionSetAssignment` links a user to a `PermissionSet` or `PermissionSetGroup`. You mean to use `PermissionSetGroupComponent` to link the `PermissionSet` to the `PermissionSetGroup`.

We can avoid a query by just using the `allOrNone` flag.

Here's the revised solution.

```
String permissionSetName = 'DE_Access_Application_Team_Assignment';
String permissionSetGroupName = 'Digital_Experience_LenderAI_PS_Group';

PermissionSet[] myPermissionSet = [SELECT Id FROM PermissionSet WHERE Name = :permissionSetName LIMIT 1];
PermissionSetGroup[] myPermissionSetGroup = [SELECT Id FROM PermissionSetGroup WHERE DeveloperName = :permissionSetGroupName LIMIT 1];

if (myPermissionSet.size() == 1 && myPermissionSetGroup.size() == 1) {
    PermissionSetGroupComponent groupComponent = new PermissionSetGroupComponent(
        PermissionSetId = myPermissionSet[0].Id,
        PermissionSetGroupId = myPermissionSetGroup[0].Id
    );

    Database.SaveResult result = Database.insert(groupComponent, false);
    if(result.success) {
        System.debug('Permission Set ' + permissionSetName + ' assigned to Permission Set Group ' + permissionSetGroupName);
    } else {
        System.debug('Permission Set ' + permissionSetName + ' was not assigned because ' + result.errors[0].getMessage());
    }
} else {
    System.debug('Permission Set or Permission Set Group not found.');
}
```

Comment: thanks it worked